Automatically position programs to a specific position with dual monitors
I am using a dual monitor setup and using Windows 10. I want to be able to hit a key and send the current window to the specific snapped position.
Basically, what this plugin does https://github.com/BarRaider/streamdeck-windowsmover
but the plugin is for stream deck which I do not have.
So, let's say I open a cmd prompt or music player and hit a hot key then they should snap to the assigned positions on the second monitor.
I am trying to achieve this with AutoHotkey but can't get it working (using ChatGPT to generate code).
Any help in this regard is helpful.
Thanks

I use nircmd win setsize for that purpose: https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html
Combine with the keyboard macro tool of your choice and you're set.

Actually, as a matter of fact, when I’m using windows I use the same tool! (+1) because I know it works.

There's a number of existing keyboard shortcuts within Windows, which may go some way towards what you're after. There are others, but these are the ones I use on a regular basis.
WIN+Left/Right will snap to one side of the current screen or the other.
SHIFT+WIN+Left/Right will move the window to the other screen.
SHIFT+WIN+Up will maximise the height of the current window (but not fully maximise it).
WIN+Up/Down will maximise / restore / minimise the current window.
